Spark produces data duplicates when it hits OOM and retry the stage
I have a Spark job that writes data into HMS table. When Spark executor hits OOM, Spark retry the whole stage, and it causes data duplication. Any ideas how to prevent duplication?
The code I use to write data:
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto(table)


I would say, you need to investigate what causes OOM and fix it. Otherwise it will hide the real issue.
It can be data skew - which can be solved by repartitioning
or you may need to increase executor memory
